# MongoDB - Count the number of distinct idUsuarios in a collection

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to count the number of distincts `idUsuarios` in collection called `reforcos` filtering by `'idOcorrencia': '54fa7df48a070f6d59c53057'`

There's the documents of collection `reforcos`

```
    /* 0 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54fa838c8a070f6d59c53126"),
    "idUsuario" : "54f59a9e91bd495c51476e87",
    "idOcorrencia" : "54fa7df48a070f6d59c53057"
}

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54fa838c8a070f6d59c53127"),
    "idUsuario" : "54f59a9e91bd495c51476e87",
    "idOcorrencia" : "54fa7df48a070f6d59c53057"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54fa838c8a070f6d59c53128"),
    "idUsuario" : "54f59a9e91bd495c51476e87",
    "idOcorrencia" : "54fa7df48a070f6d59c53057"
}
```

Comment: You could also try the aggregation framework in which the first pipeline has the $match operation on the field in question. The next pipeline then takes two "$group" commands: the first one groups by distinct values, the second one counts all of the distinct values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**db.collection.distinct**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) to get distinct idUsuarios in your collection. And since `collection.distinct` return an array you need to use [**Array.length**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) property to get the number of distinct idUsuarios.

```js
db.reforcos.distinct('idUsuario', 
    {'idOcorrencia': '54fa7df48a070f6d59c53057'}
).length
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [db.collection.distinct](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) to get list of unique `idUsuarios` with `idOcorrencia='54fa7df48a070f6d59c53057`:

```
db.reforcos.distinct('idUsuarios', {'idOcorrencia': '54fa7df48a070f6d59c53057'})
```

**Update:** To get number of distinct values, apply `.length` to result:

```
db.reforcos.distinct('idUsuarios', {'idOcorrencia': '54fa7df48a070f6d59c53057'}).length
```

Comment: its returning null but how I did post...theres 5 documents in this collections...all 'idOcorrencia': '54fa7df48a070f6d59c53057'

Comment: What query returned 5 documents that you listed?